# Getting Location of Tweets found with Twitter Search API

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, geolocation

Whenever I search for tweets using the geocode option, the returned tweets have "null" as their geo property. They are definitely coming from the right place because the location property has a name which is in the correct area, however I want to know what the coordinates of the tweet are so I can place on on a map (specifically Windows Phone).

I've tried a really hacky solution of searching for the location using the geo api, but this seems a really awkward way of doing it and often returns bad results (I want results from Oxford, UK but often the geo search return Oxford, IN for example).

Looking around, it seems Twitter's geolocation is currently broken, but I really need this to work for a presentation on Thursday demonstrating an app we built in a group, and it would really suck if our main feature didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter's search API is broken](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/79). It will not return some information which is available through the regular API.

Once you have found a Tweet, you can try looking it up directly using [statuses/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid)

For example, calling one of my tweets:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.xml?id=202471009973051393&include_entities=true
```

gives

```
<geo>
  <georss:point>51.52505194 -0.132582</georss:point>
</geo>
<coordinates>
  <georss:point>51.52505194 -0.132582</georss:point>
</coordinates>
```

Comment: I tried that, but unless the json results just don't give geo information, it still returned lots of null geo positions. I've got a really hacky solution working at the moment, so I'm only going to look into it if I have time, I'm on a tight schedule.